How to pause a coroutine job and resume later in android Kotlin?
I am developing an application that will receive a large demand for strings from a reader, as it takes a long time to collect information, I need to perform insertions into the database and check the return to update the counters. However, the user may want to pause reading and resume later.
My question would be how to make a secure call to pause the job and continue later without canceling the coroutine and stopping the database Room.
The repeat loop starts but I can't stop it without canceling the coroutine, which has consequences for the database as well.
If I wait for while to finish, I can clear the variables and charm the populateTags() function and it starts again.
Would it be possible to assign several jobs to a coroutineScope and reference them individually to monitor the states and calculate them individually and perhaps return them?
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.Default)

   fun populateTags() = scope.launch(Job()) {
        while (_readTags.value.size < 100000) {
            // call insert function
            insert(
                Tag(epc = (1..10000).random().toString())
            )
        }
    }

    fun stopPopulateTags() {
        // pause o teste
        populateTags().cancel()
    }

    private suspend fun insert(tag: Tag) {
        // insert tag in database, return -1 if not save and update the lists
        val test = tagRepository.insert(tag)
        if (test == -1L) {
            _notSaveTags.value = _notSaveTags.value.plus(tag.epc)
        } else {
            _saveTags.value = _saveTags.value.plus(tag.epc)
        }
        _readTags.value = _readTags.value.plus(tag.epc)
    }


I don't think we can forcefully make a coroutine suspend/pause. Background task has to cooperate by checking in regular intervals if it should progress or suspend. Which is easy in your case as you perform operations in a loop, so we can check with each iteration.
We can make the check by using utilities for synchronization like Mutex or Semaphore. In your case we can use CompletableJob:
private var job = Job().apply { complete() }

fun populateTags() = scope.launch(Job()) {
    while (_readTags.value.size < 100000) {
        job.join()
        // call insert function
        insert(
            Tag(epc = (1..10000).random().toString())
        )
    }
}

fun pausePopulateTags() {
    job = Job()
}

fun resumePopulateTags() {
    job.complete()
}

Please note this solution is not suitable for cases where we need to pause for longer periods of time as Android may kill the application. If you need it to work between application restarts, you need to persist the state of your background job.
